# What does $\\f(g(x)=0)$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

I saw a question on my math test like so:

Define: $f(g(x)=0),f(x)=(\frac{x^2}{6} - \frac {x}{12}), g(x)=x^2+5x+6$

Can you write this? And if so what would it mean? Could it possibly give an answer that is not $0$?

Comment: No, it does not have a meaning.

Comment: Where did you see this

Comment: You can write it if you want, but then you'd better define it. As @KaboMurphy said, it does not seem to have a clear meaning as is.

Comment: I saw this on a math test.

Comment: If someone wrote this, I guess it might means $f(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is a constant function such that $g(x)=0$

Comment: Are you sure it's not, for example $f(g(x))=0$?

Comment: you should post the whole question, since that might also just be a typo when someone want to write $f(g(x))=0$ like Matti said

Comment: May be it means $f(\{ x,g(x)=0\})$, then it is just the image of some specific set by $f$. Could you post the question where this comes from ?

Comment: It's also possible that the domain of $f$ consists of (e.g. linear) *equations*. Then it could be perfectly valid. Nevertheless, please add more context.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps $f(g^{-1}({0}))$ was meant?